# Prevent custom modal from hidding when background is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created a custom modal (not bootstrap) and would like it to make it so If I click the surrounding background, it closes the modal. However, with the code I've put together, clicking anywhere on the modal also seems to close the modal. I figure it might be something to do with z-indexing, but everthing i've tried hasn't worked.

The HTML:

```
<div class="overlay" onclick="closeModal();">
   <div class="overlay-wrap">
      <div class="modal">
          This is my modal 
          <a href="javascript:;" onclick="closeModal();">X</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display:table;
    z-index:9999;
    .overlay-wrap {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .modal {
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:left;
        min-width:300px;
        max-width:90%;
        margin: 15px;
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

The Javascript:

```
function closeModal(ev) {
    $(ev.currentTarget).closest('.overlay').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `click event` to your `.modal` and use `event.stopImmediatePropagation`. Snippet below:

```js
$(".overlay,.close").on('click',function(e){
  $(".overlay").hide();
});

$('.modal').on('click',function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();  
});
```

```css
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display:table;
    z-index:9999;
  }
    .overlay-wrap {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .modal {
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:left;
        min-width:300px;
        max-width:90%;
        margin: 15px;
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
   <div class="overlay-wrap">
      <div class="modal">
          This is my modal 
          <a class="close" href="javascript:;">X</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a listener to the modal that stops the event propagation:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal" onclick="stopEvent()">
          This is my modal 
          <a href="javascript:;" onclick="closeModal();">X</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function stopEvent(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on('click','#closeModal', function(){
  
    $('.overlay').hide()
    
  })
  
  $(document).on('click','.overlay', function(){
  
    $('.overlay').hide()
    
  })
  
})
```

```css
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display:table;
    z-index:9999;
    .overlay-wrap {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .modal {
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:left;
        min-width:300px;
        max-width:90%;
        margin: 15px;
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
   <div class="overlay-wrap">
      <div class="modal">
          This is my modal 
          <a href="javascript:;" id="closeModal">X</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Try this, Maybe this help you .